# Transform character with ranges or values into vector of only values in R

Tags: r, strsplit

I have a character vector `c("1:3","4")` and what I need is `c(1,2,3,4)`.

What I did so far was to get each element of the original vector, use `strsplit` on `"1:3"`, retrieve the numbers `1` and `3`, form the vector `c(1,2,3)` and then get the desired vector by concatenating with `4`.

Is there any simpler way of doing that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is `eval(parse`

```
unlist(lapply(v1, function(x) eval(parse(text=x))))
```

---

Or after the `strsplit`, get the sequence with `:`

```
unlist(lapply(strsplit(v1, ":"), function(x) Reduce(`:`, as.numeric(x))))
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("1:3","4")
```